# How to implement: do something if the function hasn't been called yet?

Tags: c, function, while-loop, call

Is there a way in C that you can do: if a function hasn't been called before in a previous part of the code then call it, otherwise if it has been called before then don't call it?

Heres some code:

```
while (function hasn't been called)
{
    // do some code
}
else (call the function)
{
    // do something else
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: Will `// do some code` eventually call the function or are we looking at concurrent code here?

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. Perhaps the `while` was intended to be an `if`. Otherwise, you need to explain how the the function gets called when the code is stuck in the `while` loop (as Daniel pointed out).

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's pretty easy. Just use a static variable.

```
void foo() {
    static int hasBeenCalled = 0;
    if(!hasBeenCalled) {
        /* Do stuff */
        hasBeenCalled = 1;
    }
}
```

You don't have to perform the initialization for globals and statics, since they have the default value of 0, which local variables does not. But imho it looks way better. Globals and statics are used so rarely that I don't see the point in utilizing this 'feature'.

Technically, you're still calling the function with above method. If that's a problem, you can use a global variable and put the logic I used outside. Here is a working example:

```
int hasBeenCalled = 0;

void foo() {
    while(!hasBeenCalled) {
        /* Do stuff that eventually calls bar() */
    }
}

void bar() {
    hasBeenCalled=1;
    /* Do stuff */
}

int main() {
    foo();
}
```

Comment: static int works and should be pointed out that static variables by default have an initial value of 0 and are stored in the .data section rather than local to a stack. There's nothing magical about them, it would be the same as using a global variable.

Comment: @Nina While what all you're saying is true, I don't see the point in pointing it out. I always initialize both globals and statics even if they should be set to zero.

Comment: The only problem with this technique is if the code could be used from multiple threads.  Several of them might then do the initialization at once.  POSIX provides [`pthread_once()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_once.html) to solve that problem.  It likely isn't an issue for the OP (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the code your are using to illustrate your intention is not very clear. But, you did ask this:

> ... if a function hasn't been called before in a previous part of the code then call it, otherwise if it has been called before then don't call it?

Besides using a boolean, you can also use a function pointer. The function pointer points to a function that should be called the first time the function is invoked. This function then changes the function pointer to point to the function that should be called after the first time.

```
static void foo_first_time(void);
static void foo_after_first_time(void);

void (*foo)(void) = foo_first_time;

static void foo_first_time(void) {
    foo = foo_after_first_time;
    // do some code
    // ...
}

static void foo_after_first_time(void) {
    // do something else
    // ...
}
```

Now, the caller simply invokes `foo()` normally. The first time would invoke `foo_first_time`, but subsequent calls would invoke `foo_after_first_time`.

```
int main () {
    foo(); // calls foo_first_time
    foo(); // calls foo_after_first_time
    foo(); // calls foo_after_first_time again
}
```